# How do I find all uses of a data type in a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

I'm planning an upgrade to MySQL where DATETIME, TIMESTAMP, TIME and YEAR are potentially a problem. I'd like to query the database to find all uses of these datatypes. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You plan migrate to MySQL from what? You want scan source database or target? and last - "usage" it is tables columns or insane in queries, procedures, triggers?

Answer (score 0):

The following query will search for you usage of these datatypes across a database.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "database"
      AND DATA_TYPE in ('DATETIME', 'TIME', 'TIMESTAMP',
                        'YEAR(2)', 'YEAR(4)', 'YEAR');
```

Comment: Grab `TABLE_NAME`, too.